# Arduino line following robot for beginners in C++(Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working on a school project with very little resources. I need to make a line following robot which finds the way through a maze by turning left when possible. I already have a small body, but the robot doesn't seem to turn left/follow the line when needed. I also have no clue how I can get rid of small deviations and how I can make the robot turn when there are no more lines?

**Materials:**

- Arduino Leonardo
- qtr-8a ground sensor
- two basic DC motors

**Code:**

```cpp
#include <DRV8835MotorShield.h>  //setup for motors
DRV8835MotorShield motors;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  motors.flipM1(true);
  motors.flipM2(true);

}

void loop() {
  //left groundsensor= analogRead(A0);
  //rightgroundsensor = analogRead(A2);
  //middlegroundsensor = analogRead(A1);
  //motorstM1//right weel
  //motors.setM2Speed(100);//left weel
  if(analogRead(A0) > 750){ //turn left
    motors.setM1Speed(100);
    motors.setM2Speed(-100);
  }
  else if(analogRead(A1) > 750){//nothing left, so go straight
    motors.setM1Speed(100);
    motors.setM2Speed(100); 
  }
  else if(analogRead(A2) > 750){//nothing in the middle, so robot has deviated, turn right a bit, if the deviation is to the rigth, I don't need the next loop
    while(analogRead(A0) < 750){//turn right till black line is in the middle again
      motors.setM1Speed(-100);
      motors.setM1Speed(100);
    }
  }
  else{//if they are all < 750, it's a deviation or a dead end, I will have to watch how the robot deviates so that I can turn let it always turn in the opposite direction
    while(analogRead(A1) < 750){//turn right/left till black line is in the middle again
      motors.setM1Speed(-100);
      motors.setM1Speed(100);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in the second `while` aren't you missing a `}` before the third `while`?

Comment: I think this can be simplified to: `motors.setM1Speed(analogRead(A1) / 10); motors.setM2Speed(analogRead(A0) / 10); delay(10);`

Comment: @JohnDoe, That's right, just forgot to copy that one from the original code.

Comment: You have to catch the case where the middle sensor looses the line and then turn right. And use `if` instead of `while`. The loop already repeats the code over and over, no need to loop again in a blocking way.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, ok, thanks for helping me with the deviations, but what did you mean with your first comment? I don't really get it.

Comment: Whatever side drifts of the line turns on the opposite motor. If black gives a high value then you have to invert the speed. My own sensor reports the light level so white is high. But I'm thinking to simple, just following a line. But a maze I assume has branches. The really simple line following won't work with branches.

Comment: Yes, it is a line with branches, so your idea works for driving forward? Then I should only figure out how I can optimize the turns? without triggering the straight forward riding?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I gues there is another problem with your idea, since there is quite a large gap between the sensors, only one at a time can see the black line, so if the middle one moves away from it, then it has the same value as the left one...

Comment: If the line can be between sensors without either one detecting the line then you have to steer so both always remain white. If one sees black steer away from it. If both see black you hit a turn or branch so steer left. It gives you a different table than in my answer. Makes it a lot easier to loose the line though, so you have to react fast or you drive over the line before you can turn back.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, I changed the program in the post to what I have now, do you think this will work? (I don't have the robot at home)

Comment: Drop the while, the loop will already keep the robot turning till things change

Answer (score 0):

```
//left groundsensor= analogRead(A0);
//rightgroundsensor = analogRead(A2);
//middlegroundsensor = analogRead(A1);
```

I'm assuming the line is wide enough that it can not be between 2 sensors and have both sensors report white. Correct?

Lets consider all the cases the car can run into:

1. Straight line

Ideally left should be white and middle black. In that case drive straight. But the car will drift left or right.

If A0 gets black turn more to the left. If A1 gets white turn more to the right.

2. Left turn, Left Branch

A0 and A1 both turn black, turn to the left.

3. 4 way cross

A0, A1 and A2 turn black, turn to the left.

4. Right branch

A2 turns black, keep going straight

5. Right turn

A2 turns black and a bit later A1 turns white, turn right

As you see A2 can be ignored. And if you merge all the cases you get:

```
| A0    | A1    | movement
| white | white | turn right
| white | black | straight
| black | white | turn left or right, shouldn't really be happening 
| black | black | turn left
```

So check for those 4 cases in `loop()` with a small delay and it should solve the maze.

Note: If the car gets stuck turning one direction for a long time you might want to go a bit straight. If the line is too thick you might just turn on the line and never see the edge. If you have white, white driving in a spiral to find the line again could help. Both cases indicate your loop is too slow or your speed to high. You should never loose the edge of the line.

Comment: Yep, that's right, thanks a lot! Gues I can complete the project right now!